# Hardware Info - Both Windows and Linux

Tags: hardware, system-monitor

So I am always interested in knowing exactly the components and statistics make up a machine. The stock standard Device Manager and System Info tools are quite helpful, but alas lacking a little knowledge. I have tried running systeminfo in command line but would really appreciate a GUI for it. Possibly the best solution I have found so far is [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/), which works well on my Window's PC.

The question I then raised would be, what software would I use if I made my File Server Linux based? It would be preferable for it to be as detailed and structured as AID64 (I wonder if I could emulate this on Linux!?) Here are some examples of what AIDA64 provides me:

[image: Main Page]

From there you are then able to break down each section for more detailed information, which is probably overkill for most, but definitely handy when needed. I would not expect a Linux program to be able to detect this much information (although I am sure it possible), but it would be nice to have such a tool. The breakdown of the information is clean and informative  like so:

[image: Example CPU]

Also, apart from device detection etc it will allow a user to perform such test like stability tests (Image as follows) and driver tests etc.

[image: System Stability]

Is there any software tool available on Linux the performs this sort of analysis and function, or could I create a script to detail me this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one you could try is I-Nex . See https://github.com/eloaders/I-Nex

[image: I-Nex system image]

I'm sure this would be more of your liking :)

On the bottom, there is a generate report so you can generate reports. The only thing it doesn't have is benchmarking. But for that you have the phoronix-test-suite which can do the needful for you :)

Comment: shirish, Thank you for your alternative. After work I will attempt to use this and will advise/mark your answer as my answer. Thank you for the link!

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow would be looking forward to knowing your experience. A word of caution though about the phoronix-test-suite. It's brutal on the system, so unless you have a good beefy system wouldn't suggest to go there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `lshw` utility. Although it is a command line tool, there is a GTK GUI for it. It can also output HTML report. Note that to get the most information, it must be run as superuser.

Example command:

```
su lshw -html > report.html
```

If you run this in the correct directory and name the report as `index.html` you can view it as a webpage.

Unfortunately this is a Linux only tool and it has no benchmarking or system testing features.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The GUI isn't imperative, command line is always good. I will try this today and see what information it can export for me. There is always the ability to use AID64 on my Windows machine and this on Linux.